# How can I access the observableArray in my click event?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a project where I cannot figure out how to access the observableArray from a click event as called from the container template. I have a stripped down example in a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zBarW/26/

The click event is specified in a template which then dynamically loads a template for each item from a property on the item itself.

So an example item is:

```
{ID: 1, TemplateName: 'template1', Label: 'Name', Description: 'Your name'}
```

The "parent" template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tpl-placeholder">
<div class="entry" data-bind="click: $parent.RemoveEntry, attr: { id: ID}, template: {name: TemplateName }"></div>
</script>
```

And a dynamically loaded template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template1">
    <h1 data-bind="text: Label"></h1>
    <div data-bind="text: Description"></div>
</script>
```

In the method that handles the click event - in this case, RemoveEntry - I get null when trying to access the observableArray (Entries).

Here is the viewmodel:

```
var viewModel = {

    Name: ko.observable("Entries"),

    Entries: ko.observableArray( entries ),

    RemoveEntry: function (entry) {
        // how do I access the "Entries" list here - this.Entries returns null
        $("#debug").text(this.Entries == null);
        this.Entries.remove(entry);
    }
};
```

I am a knockout newb .. can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you have it,  you directly access viewmodel.Entries...

however, more typically you'd do it like :-

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/RAMcc/

with the good ol javascript hack

```
var self = this;
```

Comment: Hi Keith, looks like I answered my own question and the same time you posted this. Did you notice that your fiddle is not working? The templates are not loading.

Comment: yeah, I just noticed how you were doing it, which isn't the way people normally do viewmodels, so I just added a fiddle with whats commonly done

Answer (score 0):

In my original test, I found that I could use **viewModel.Entries**. I think Keith's response is better, it is definitely the more typical method. I'll leave this here for completeness.

For my example, this works:

```
RemoveEntry: function (entry) {
    // how do I access the "Entries" list here - this.Entries returns null
    $("#debug").text(viewModel.Entries == null);
    viewModel.Entries.remove(entry);
}
```